# Should I use Python in stead of VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-access-2007

I am been building a demo (and potentially a small application) for a financial accounting model. I am using VBA/Excel for data input (eg with forms), calculations and presentation of results and I am also running SQL-questions to MS Access database from the VBA program. In principle, the functionality of these components serve me fairly well (I realize that VBA is a bit ouot dated and not the smoothest).
I have been doing this for some time now (and I am engineer with some ancient experience of other languages, although never worked as a programmer) and fell pretty much on top of things and seem to be able to find the programming errors I make. However, I tend to go mad at VBA when faults occur that really don't seem to be caused by me, but due instability/shortcomings with VBA.

So my question is, being completely inexperiened with Python: could I basically do with Python that I descibed above? Could you give me an idea of whether Python is more stable and less "error prone" than VBA/Excel? (am using Windows 7)
Grateful for advice

Comment: It always depends on what exactly you are trying to do with your VBA procedures, having said that however; VBA can be very stable if it is well written, do you have any examples of the error's that sometimes occur with a code sample?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see anything, which examples?

Comment: - when I was dealing with "shape", the system returned an error (forgot the exact formulation/error number), to which I found the solution: Dim s1, s2 as Shape should be written Dim s1,s2,s3 as Shape. The key seems to be that I add s3, which is not used, to make it work. At least the error comes back if I take it away. This has happened more than once.  - Sometimes the system says that there is no record (from an SQL-query), although there is one (I have tried the same query directly in Access).

Comment: When you dimesion like that "Dim s1, s2 As Shape" only the last value will be a shape, the others will default to Variant, so they should each be declared on a separate line one by one.  How are you testing whether there is no record, .EOF will suffice for ADO, but if using DAO then you will need both .BOF And .EOF, could you be a little more specific please?

Comment: Thanks Matt, for the info on Shape, which was helpful. I use ADO. When I run the program the system stops the execution and presents Error 3021 " ... operation requires a current record". Then, when I go into ACCESS and use the SQL query I get the answer I expect.

Comment: Have you tried using a "MoveFirst" after opening the ADO recordset?

Comment: Yes, actually I have (obviously I did not get that into the code "quote").

Comment: I'm a little stuck on that one then, is there anyway of posting a fuller code sample including where the error occurs please?

Comment: FWIW: regarding your initial question of python vs. VBA... 1) You should include the python tag in order to get the attention of the python experts. 2) If you are creating a tool within Excel, stick to VBA. If you are looking to automate Excel & Access you could use python, but you'd still be building forms in Excel, so you'd still have macros/VBA.  3) Python is a wonderful language, but in this instance VBA seems much more appropriate.

Comment: I have now included relevant parts of the code in the question. When I think the Shape-issue over it puzzles me. According to that rule only the variable just before (s3) "as Shape" should function as shape, right? But what happens is that the s2 does not function as shape while it stands just before "as Shape" (without s3) and only starts working as such when s3 is put to the right of s2 and just before "as Shape". I figure that that is not the way the rule should work, or...?

Answer (score 11):

If you decide to use Python to drive automation of Office applications, look into [Python Win32 Extensions](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html)

However, I'm skeptical that is advisable.  It would require you to install and learn Python.  And if this is an application you distribute to users, they would need Python installed as well.

Furthermore the example you provided about declaring variables suggests your time would be better spent learning VBA and the object models of the Office applications you want to automate.  In that example, you misinterpreted your lack of understanding of VBA fundamentals as "VBA is error prone".  Python won't help you with that.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go away. How could I include a longer piece of code my comment? I get "-xx characters left" when I try to paste it into the comment.

Comment: @user1164822 You can host code in GitHub or [start a chat](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

Comment: You should try `xlwings` as per the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600540/4752883

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you do this in Python. Python has become the defacto standard for data analysis. Microsoft is considering adding `Python` to excel: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15927132

But it hasn't been added yet: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10549005-python-as-an-excel-scripting-language

Nonetheless, everything you can do in `VBA` can be done through python and more using any of the following libraries:

1. `Xlwings`: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings
2. `Pywin32`: https://github.com/Googulator/pypiwin32
3. `Pyspread`: https://manns.github.io/pyspread/
4. `Xlswriter`/`Xlsread`

Of these I would suggest you use `xlwings`. I have used it and it works flawlessly. You can even execute `VBA` through python code. So you have the best of both worlds, i.e. use any data-analysis package in python to do your computation, and when you need to(but dont have access to the functions exposed by VBA, but not supported natively by `xlwings`) you can directly call `VBA` functions in Excel.